Emails not being sent from a quick action linked to LWC
I recently created an LWC to use as a quick action in the case field, to send a specific email with one click, I also created the class to call the records that I would need. I configured singleEmailMessage and everything else, after testing, the method works, and the parameters are correct, but the email does not reach the destination. I'm testing in a test sandbox. Could anyone help me figure out why the emails aren't arriving in my inbox?
Follow the codes
public with sharing class MailSenderClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void sendEmail(String caseId) {
        // Consulta o caso e o e-mail do contato vinculado
        Case caseRecord = [SELECT Id, SuppliedEmail, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId LIMIT 1];
        User userRecord = [SELECT Id, email FROM User WHERE id = : caseRecord.OwnerId LIMIT 1];
        String toAddress = caseRecord.SuppliedEmail;

        // Criação do e-mail
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { toAddress });
        mail.setTargetObjectId(userRecord.Id);
        mail.setTemplateId('00X88000001386vEAA');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName(userRecord.email);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);


        System.debug('Endereço de e-mail destino: ' + mail.getToAddresses());
        System.debug('Assunto do e-mail: ' + mail.getSubject());
        System.debug('Corpo do e-mail: ' + mail.getTemplateId());
        System.debug('What ID' + mail.getWhatId());
        System.debug('Sender' + mail.getSenderDisplayName());
        System.debug('Nome template' + mail.getTemplateName());

        // Envia o e-mail
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        System.debug('E-mail enviado para: ' + toAddress);
    }
} 

import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import sendEmail from '@salesforce/apex/MailSenderClass.sendEmail';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';

export default class EmailSender extends LightningElement {
    
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    if (currentPageReference) {
        this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.recordId;
        }
    }

     connectedCallback() {
        
        console.log('CaseEmailSender component loaded.');
        console.log('Record ID:', this.recordId);
        console.log('Email enviado para', this.toAddress)
    }

     handleSendEmail() {
        sendEmail({ caseId: this.recordId })
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Sucesso',
                        message: 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
                this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Erro',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}


Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I'd like to commend you on the quality of your post. For future reference, though, the code-block format (triple backtick) must be on its own line for proper formatting (I've edited it for you this time). Aside from that, could you confirm that (a) no exceptions are thrown, (b) your sandbox's Email Deliverability settings are set to All Emails, (c) you've checked the Email Logs in Setup to make sure the emails were not rejected, and (d) you've checked your spam folder in your email client?

Hello, thank you for editing the post!, I checked the points mentioned by you, they all appear to be correct, but when I went to check the logs, I noticed that the unsent emails, marked as 'P', contain this error in the Delivery Status Notification: "Unauthenticated email from premierpet.com.br is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of premierpet.com.br domain if this was a legitimate mail. To learn about the DMARC initiative, go to
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=DmarcRejection 41be03b00d2f7-72749d24746si1252145a12.592 - gsmtp"

Since you found the following error in your email log:

Unauthenticated email from premierpet.com.br is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of premierpet.com.br domain if this was a legitimate mail.

This means you'll have to configure DKIM and SPF for the domain. If you do not own the domain, you may not be able to set this up. In that case, you'll need to use an alternative email address, such as a gmail.com, yahoo.com, outlook.com/live.com, etc email address.
